# Cannot copy script to Google Script Project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy this source http://pastebin.com/s7v5x4jk to a file a in a Google Script project for a spreadsheet. The problem is that not all the text gets copied when I do a copy and paste. Is there a way to upload files to Script Projects or to get around this? 
How to replicate:
Open a Google Spreadsheet, go to Tools->Script Editor and create a new project, try to copy all the text to the file.

Comment: You can copied in two stages (first half and second) or make a copy of [my project](http://goo.gl/rtz9T);) but i do not know will it work with google apps script

Answer (score 0):

You've got one very long line, perhaps that's overwhelming the editor. (There are 132000+ characters in line 10.)

You will able to paste the code into an Apps Script file by putting it through a [prettifier](http://www.jspretty.com/) first. A better alternative would be to use [the development version](http://github.com/downloads/dmajda/pegjs/peg-0.7.0.js), which isn't minified.